# Compute the possible square roots

Tags: complex-numbers

compute the square root of 1 + i√3

I'm not sure if i am approaching this right but would it be √1+ √i√√3. then this square root of 1 equals 1, the square root of i equals -1, and then square root of three being squared again just equals 3. so then the answer is -2.

Comment: You have a fairly original understanding of arithmetic laws and complex numbers...

Comment: This is hard to follow, but I think you are (falsely) claiming that $\sqrt {a+b}=\sqrt a +\sqrt b$.

Comment: @lulu: and $\sqrt i=-1$ and $\sqrt{\sqrt x}=(\sqrt x)^2$ ?!

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Yes...I didn't even try to decode that part.

Comment: It is $i^2=-1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve

$$z^2=1+i\sqrt3.$$

With $z=a+ib$,

$$a^2-b^2+i2ab=1+i\sqrt3.$$

Then after identification of the real and imaginary parts

$$(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2=1^2+(\sqrt3)^2=2^2=(a^2+b^2)^2$$

so that ($a^2+b^2$ cannot be negative),

$$a^2-b^2+a^2+b^2=2a^2=1+2.$$

The solutions are

$$a=\pm\sqrt{\frac32}$$ with

$$b=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: (+1): This is the preferred way to do it for people new to complex numbers. But I think it would for OP to note that this method works because the real part of the right-hand-side equals the real part of the left-hand-side (and vice versa for the imaginary part).

Comment: @Jam: I made it slightly more obvious (by $5\%$).

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a lot going on here.  First, you're mixing up "squaring" with "square root."  For instance, the square root of $\sqrt{3}$ isn't $3$, rather $\sqrt{\sqrt{3}}$.

Second, square-rooting doesn't distribute over addition.  You can't write this:

$$5 = \sqrt{25} = \sqrt{9+16} =\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{16} = 3 + 4 = 7$$

because 5 does not equal 7.  The error occurs at the third equal sign where we split the square root into two piece.   So that's a no-no.

Instead, I bet you're supposed to put the complex number in "polar form."  If you can do that, you're more than half-way there.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things. It's as easy as finding all possible combinations of $a$ and $b$ such that $(a+bi)^2=1+i\sqrt{3}$